# How to change attribute where image is attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

Do you know how to change the attribute where a file uploaded with Carrierwave is attached to a user ? For example , i have a @user.photo with the attached file and i want the @user.previous_photo to have the same file attached. ( without reuploading the photo )

version Rails 5

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
@user.remote_previous_photo_url= @user.photo
@user.save
```